# slotDuration 15 minutes breaks the grid for 30 minutes in row

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to implement 15 minutes slot duration. I am using VueJs (:slotDuration="'00:15:00'") and it works but the rows in the grid becomes 30 minutes duration, by default they are 1 hour.

So is there a way to have 1 hour row cell in which there are 4 slots with 15 minutes each.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, found the solution.
 :slotLabelInterval="'1:00'"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, found the solution myself.

```
:slotLabelInterval="'1:00'"
```